# Visual Studio Code Extensions are stuck on Installing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running the latest version of visual studio code on Windows 11 (v1.77.3).

When I try to install any extension in the visual studio code extension marketplace, it says installing but never installs.

I tried editing config files and looking through different answers on the internet but found nothing, if you're having this same problem the solution is much simpler than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to right-click on the VSCode desktop icon and run this app as administrator, I am not sure why this changes whether or not you can install vscode extensions, but it works. *note: this will only work for windows users*.